# Filling a screen width

Tags: css, html, width

I'm really struggling to tidy up a web site I am building for someone.
I've spent hours on trying to figure this out! I have limited knowledge so the code would be helpful. They want the section at the top (originally two images, now I'm trying background images and css) to fill the width of the browser- no matter what size it is. Does anyone know how to do this?

Similarly, is there a setting to get text to fill 100% width of the box, no matter what?

I would seriously appreciate even someone helping me move on a step! they want everything to sit tight and inline, in some browsers/screens it does but on mine it spreads out with lots of white space.

[www.thegees.co.uk](http://www.thegees.co.uk) is the site.

Comment: You might want to check out http://doctype.com - answering CSS questions with neither images nor code is ... hard

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "text", and I'm not sure whether this will help you but any block level container will have 100% width by default:

```
<div style="background-color: red">I'm 100% wide!</div>
```

If you have a `span` that won't stretch to 100%, put a `div` around it and whatever background properties the span has, give the `div` instead.

```
<div style="background-image: ....">
 <span>
   I'm not 100% wide, but the div around me is, 
   so no one will notice the difference!
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "width" definition from these two tags:

< TD width="48%">...< /TD>
< TD width="52%">...< /TD>